# ASP.NET Outputcache when doing a ajax call and posting json

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, outputcache

I'm trying to outputcache a action method in asp.net mvc. The method returns json and is called by jquery $.ajax, data in the call is json. How can I make the outputcache vary by the json sent to the method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use OutputCache and VaryByParam="*"

```
    [HttpPost]
    [OutputCache(VaryByParam="*",Duration=10)]
    public ActionResult TestOutputCache(Entry entry)
    {            
        return  Content(entry.Description + " " + DateTime.Now,"text/plain");
    }
```

This will add any POST buffer that's different and cache it individually.

Unless you know you'll have many recurring values this is not a great idea though as your cache may get large with many values quickly.